# how to execute php script in ios parse-server side?

Tags: php, ios, parse-server

my iOS swift app is deployed in heroku 
using Parse SDK, my question is how to execute php script in parse-server side when an action  happend in ios app , eg: send  confirmation email when new user signup using ios app by executing php script in the server side.

any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Parse server is based on NodeJS and not PHP. the only scripts that you can execute in parse-server should be written in NodeJS. If you have some 3-party scripts written in PHP and those scripts are exposed in REST api you have 2 options:

1. Call those scripts from within the parse-server cloud code env. (with a very simple NodeJS call to your php rest API)
2. call those scripts from within your IOS client and handle the results on the client

[EDIT] in order to execute scripts when events occurs (e.g. user created, class updated etc) you can use cloud code triggers

for example a code that will be executed before a user is saved to the database is (from parse cloud code docs) :

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
  if (!request.object.get("email")) {
    response.error("email is required for signup");
  } else {
    response.success();
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, any idea about how to execute that NodeJS script after an action in ios app happens, eg : new user signup ??

Comment: Thanks my friend, another question please: why cloud code should be stored in my local computer not in the server side (cloud code such as index.js & main.js)

Comment: Cloud code is not stored on your local PC it stored on parse-server (under the cloud folder). When you test parse-server locally on your machine all parse-server resources should be stored on your machine but when you ready you can deploy parse-server to any cloud provider out there (e.g. AWS, AZURE, Goole etc.) and when you deploy also your cloud code will be deployed.

Comment: i already deployed parse-server to heroku , but now i need to modify main.js that under cloud folder from heroku dashboard (heroku site itself)

Comment: @Abdulelah.k you will need to change your file on your local parse-server and redeploy it again. Or using Heroku (i didn't tried it) you have an access to your file and then you can just update it, in this case it is better to use source control (like git etc.) in order to make sure that your local files will be synced with your deployed version. Since i am not familiar enough with Heroku i suggest you to check if Heroku deploy your app via git .